# Reordering elements of lists in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a list of lists composed of elements that are strings and integers, e.g.

```
a = [['i','j',1,2,3...n], ['k','l',4,5,6...n], ['m','n',7,8,9...n]]
```

I would like to reorder the string elements in each sub list such that `a[l][1]` takes the place of `a[l][0]` and vice versa, so I end up with:

```
a = [['j','i',1,2,3...n], ['l','k',4,5,6...n], ['n','m',7,8,9...n]]
```

I have tried iterating through each sub list and using an `order` variable to change the integer positions, but it does not seem to change the ordering in each list:

```
order = [1,0,2,3,4...n]

for l in reversed(range(len(a))):
    [a[l][j] for j in order]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the `reversed(...)` on the indices? It doesn't really change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [a[l][j] for j in order]
> ```

This is just an expression that is evaluated and then discarded.

If you want to change `a`, you need to *assign* to it:

```
a[l] = [a[l][j] for j in order]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest for the concrete issue would be slice assignment in a loop:

```
for sub in a:
    sub[:2] = reversed(sub[:2])
```

With your general order approach, you could do:

```
for sub in a:
    sub[:] = [sub[i] for i in order]  # needs to mutate the actual object!
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this code:

```
a[1][1], a[1][0] = a[1][0] , a[1][1]
```

thanks to python

Comment: He wants to do that for ***all*** sub-lists, not just the second one...